# tensorflow build fail at october 6 2016

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

Ubuntu 16.04

gcc 5.4.0

java 1.8.0_91

bazel 0.3.1 (download the releases , haven't build from source because it build fail)

I change the config file follow the discussion [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4371) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4312) because it works for `./configure`.

I clone the lastest code and configure **without** GPU. Here is my build instruction at the root directory of tensorflow

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

The error log:

```
ERROR: /home/gt/.cache/bazel/_bazel_gt/3d5d29ec73796bda2fc5b2dffed26f47/external/protobuf/BUILD:333:1: Linking of rule '@protobuf//:protoc' failed: gcc failed: error executing command /usr/bin/gcc -o bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/protoc -Wl,-no-as-needed -B/usr/bin -B/usr/bin -pass-exit-codes '-Wl,--build-id=md5' '-Wl,--hash-style=gnu' -Wl,-S -Wl,--gc-sections ... (remaining 1 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/_objs/protoc/external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text.startup.main+0x2db): undefined reference to `vtable for google::protobuf::compiler::php::Generator'
main.cc:(.text.startup.main+0x642): undefined reference to `vtable for google::protobuf::compiler::php::Generator'
main.cc:(.text.startup.main+0x740): undefined reference to `vtable for google::protobuf::compiler::php::Generator'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in protobuf, we signaled it already two weeks ago. See https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/2133

Comment: Thank you very much . How do the developers check the code runtime-result without build it ?